# Compare a multidimensional array with a standard array and fill in missing values

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [Recycling] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 7040
            [Jul 14] => 3920
            [Aug 14] => 14560
            [Sep 14] => 15120
            [Oct 14] => 12420
            [Nov 14] => 13440
            [Dec 14] => 13720
            [Jan 15] => 3920
        )

    [Disposal (Landfill)] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 3800
            [Jun 14] => 7820
            [Jul 14] => 8100
            [Aug 14] => 5520
        )

    [Energy Recovery] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 340
            [Jun 14] => 8500
            [Jul 14] => 6640
            [Aug 14] => 2860
            [Sep 14] => 7360
            [Oct 14] => 5380
            [Nov 14] => 8380
            [Dec 14] => 5440
            [Jan 15] => 1600
        )

)
```

Which is generated using the following query:

```
    $whmOutput = array();
    foreach ($wasteHierMon as $whm) {
        $dateChanged = date("M y", strtotime($whm['completionDate']));
         // if not defined, define with value zero
        if (!isset($whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged])) {
            $whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged] = 0;
        }
        // addition will always work now
        $whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged] += $whm['totalTonne'];

    }
```

The problem I have is that the 2nd level part of the array won't always have a value (which can be seen with both the `Recycling` & `Disposal` parts of the array.

I have another array using this code:

```
        $minValue = min($wasteHierMon);

        $minDate = $minValue['completionDate'];

        $time1  = strtotime($minDate);
        $time2  = strtotime($de);
        $my     = date('M y', $time2);

        $months = array(date('M y', $time1));

        while($time1 < $time2) {
          $time1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $time1).' +1 month');
          if(date('mY', $time1) != $my && ($time1 < $time2))
             $months[] = date('M y', $time1);
        }

        $months[] = date('M y', $time2);
```

This generates the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => May 14
    [1] => Jun 14
    [2] => Jul 14
    [3] => Aug 14
    [4] => Sep 14
    [5] => Oct 14
    [6] => Nov 14
    [7] => Dec 14
    [8] => Jan 15
)
```

This array is generated by finding the lowest/oldest date in the first array and generating each month between that date and the current date. With this array, I'd like to compare it to the first array and when a date is missing from the first array, and then add the missing date along with a value of '0' to it.

So the finished array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [Recycling] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 7040
            [Jun 14] => 0
            [Jul 14] => 3920
            [Aug 14] => 14560
            [Sep 14] => 15120
            [Oct 14] => 12420
            [Nov 14] => 13440
            [Dec 14] => 13720
            [Jan 15] => 3920
        )

    [Disposal (Landfill)] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 3800
            [Jun 14] => 7820
            [Jul 14] => 8100
            [Aug 14] => 5520
            [Sep 14] => 0
            [Oct 14] => 0
            [Nov 14] => 0
            [Dec 14] => 0
            [Jan 15] => 0
        )

    [Energy Recovery] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 340
            [Jun 14] => 8500
            [Jul 14] => 6640
            [Aug 14] => 2860
            [Sep 14] => 7360
            [Oct 14] => 5380
            [Nov 14] => 8380
            [Dec 14] => 5440
            [Jan 15] => 1600
        )

)
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
Here is the query. It's built in Symfony2:

```
    $wasteHierarchyMonth = $dm->createQuery('
        SELECT SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne, efu.wasteHierarchy, efu.completionDate
        FROM CoreBundle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu
        WHERE efu.customerSite = :site
        AND efu.completionDate != :blank
        AND efu.wasteHierarchy != :blank
        GROUP BY efu.completionDate
        ORDER BY efu.completionDate ASC'
    )->setParameters(array(
        'site' => $cs,
        'blank' => ''
    ));

    $wasteHierMon = $wasteHierarchyMonth->getResult();
```

Comment: Can you show your actual query?  I would guess you might have opportunity to actually solve this problem in your query, perhaps using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Updated the question with my query.

Answer (score 0):

If Left join isn't an option, you'll have to complete fields by hand. You can apply this strategy if you like:

Define an array of keys and run the code you expose as you usually do storing in the array of keys all the valid dates with value 0. Then go over the final array and apply a merge between the array of keys and the stored arrays:

```
$whmOutput = array();
$keys = array();// Define array of keys.

foreach ($wasteHierMon as $whm) {// Run it (I guess you do) for the three of them.
    // Your code goes here.
    ....
    // Add this line at the end.
    $keys[$dateChanged] = 0; // Store the date and value 0 in the array called keys
}
```

Once you've run your script for the different parts of the resultant array, `$keys` will contain all dates with value 0 (no duplicates). Now, taken advantage of the circumstance that the keys of the array are strings, [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) it:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.

```
foreach($whmOutput as $key => $value) {
    $whmOutput[$key] = array_merge($keys, $value);// $keys goes first because you want to override values when there's a coincidence.
}
```

I haven't tried it, but I think it should work.